# C#, Operator '??' cannot be applied to operands of type 'decimal' and 'decimal'

Tags: c#, asp.net

```
public decimal v1 {
  get {
    return this._v1; 
  }
  set {
    this._v1 = value ?? 0M;  // also I tried, default(decimal)
  }
}
```

Error message say :

**Operator '??' cannot be applied to operands of type 'decimal' and 'decimal'**

Why it does not work, and how should I do make it works?

Comment: Those are value types and cannot be `null`

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The `decimal` type cannot be null, so the null-coalesce operator makes no sense here. Just set `_v1` to `value`.

Comment: What if you have a nullable decimal? Example public decimal? TotalAmount

Comment: If the decimal is nullable then the coalesce will work,

Answer (score 5):

Those are value types and cannot be `null` you can use the `Nullable<decimal>`

```
private decimal? _v1;
public decimal? V1
{
    get
    {
        return this._v1;
    }
    set
    {
        this._v1 = value ?? 0M;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 3):

is it a decimal? or a decimal

the ?? works with a decimal? but not a decimal since a decimal can never be null.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173224.aspx

Answer (score 1):

That is the [Null Coalescing Operator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173224.aspx). Since decimal can't be null, it has no use with decimal.

You can use a `decimal?` which can be set to null if you need this functionality:

```
public decimal? v1 
{
    get 
    {
        return this._v1; 
    }
    set 
    {
        this._v1 = value ?? 0M;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you consider the **default decimal value 0** to be considered as *null, empty, or not set*, and you want to **use `value` only if it's not zero**, then you can do something like this:

```
decimal nextBest = 10M;

public decimal v1 {
  get {
    return this._v1; 
  }
  set {
    // Use value by default (only if it's not 0), Otherwise use a different number.
    this._v1 = (value != 0)? value : nextBest;  
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're trying to do this against a property of a class Ie:

```
public class TestCase {
     public decimal TestProp {get;set;}
}
```

You can do a null coallesce like this:

```
var testCase = new TestCase();
return testCase?.TestProp ?? 0M
```